# Intento sumar cada posicion de la columna 0 de la array posicion y almacenarla en el array transito

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Version2 {

    static double procesos[][];
    static int n;
    static double tiempo=0;
    static double transito[];
    static double diferencia=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        generarDatos();
        System.out.println("\nDatos aleatorios");     
        imprimirDatos();
        ordernar_Tprocesamiento();
        System.out.println("\nDatos ordenados");        
        imprimirDatos();
        Ttransito();




    }

    private static void generarDatos() {
        Random valores = new Random();
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Entre el numero de tareas: ");
        n = entrada.nextInt();

        // Crea el vector nombre y la matriz examen
        procesos = new double[n][2];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                procesos[i][j] = valores.nextGaussian()*10 +100;
            }
        }
    }


        //En la posición 0,0 de la matriz se define el tiempo de procesamiento
        //En la posición 1,0 de la matriz se define el plazo faltante

    private static void imprimirDatos() {

        for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
            System.out.print("\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

                    System.out.printf(String.format("%.2f", procesos[i][j]) + "   ");                 
            }
        }
    }
    //Ordena por tiempo de procesamiento

    private static void ordernar_Tprocesamiento() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
                if (procesos[j][0] > procesos[j + 1][0]) {
                    // Intercambia dos filas de la matriz
                    double[] filaTemp = procesos[j];
                    procesos[j] = procesos[j + 1];
                    procesos[j + 1] = filaTemp;

                }
            }

        }


    }  

    // aqui se me presenta el error, al tratar de sumar las posiciones de la primera columna del array posicion 
   private static void Ttransito(){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){

                tiempo = tiempo + procesos[i][0];
                    transito[i]=tiempo;

    }

  }
}
```

Al final arroja este error

Entre el numero de tareas: 5

Datos aleatorios

102,38   84,59
101,22   87,27
117,50   102,96
110,34   103,68
102,50   99,03
Datos ordenados

101,22   87,27
102,38   84,59
102,50   99,03
110,34   103,68
117,50   102,96   102.37715253750525

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   Version2.Ttransito(Version2.java:84)  at
>   Version2.main(Version2.java:23)

Answer (score 0):

Como bien te dice el error, el problema está en que estás intentando meter un array en una variable que ni siquiera es un array y por esoes nulo.

Lo primero es declarar bien el array `transito`:

```
double[] transito; //Ahora si que es un array de dobles
```

En segundo lugar hace falta declarar el tamaño de este array. Por lo que al calcular el `int n`, que es el tamaño que le quieres dar, se lo pasamos al array:

```
transito = new double[n]; //Ajusta tamaño del array
```

Y todo el código se vería así:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Version2 {

    static double procesos[][];
    static int n;
    static double tiempo=0;
    static double[] transito;
    static double diferencia=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        generarDatos();
        System.out.println("\nDatos aleatorios");     
        imprimirDatos();
        ordernar_Tprocesamiento();
        System.out.println("\nDatos ordenados");        
        imprimirDatos();
        Ttransito();




    }

    private static void generarDatos() {
        Random valores = new Random();
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Entre el numero de tareas: ");
        n = entrada.nextInt();
        transito = new double[n];
        // Crea el vector nombre y la matriz examen
        procesos = new double[n][2];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                procesos[i][j] = valores.nextGaussian()*10 +100;
            }
        }
    }


        //En la posición 0,0 de la matriz se define el tiempo de procesamiento
        //En la posición 1,0 de la matriz se define el plazo faltante

    private static void imprimirDatos() {

        for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
            System.out.print("\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

                    System.out.printf(String.format("%.2f", procesos[i][j]) + "   ");                 
            }
        }
    }
    //Ordena por tiempo de procesamiento

    private static void ordernar_Tprocesamiento() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
                if (procesos[j][0] > procesos[j + 1][0]) {
                    // Intercambia dos filas de la matriz
                    double[] filaTemp = procesos[j];
                    procesos[j] = procesos[j + 1];
                    procesos[j + 1] = filaTemp;

                }
            }

        }


    }  

    // aqui se me presenta el error, al tratar de sumar las posiciones de la primera columna del array posicion 
   private static void Ttransito(){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){

                tiempo = tiempo + procesos[i][0];
                    transito[i]=tiempo;

    }

  }
}
```